# How many more non-wizard spells can an Order of Scribes wizard get that are either a new source of damage type or new use of damage types?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, wizard

A few setting specific backgrounds (such as the *Izzet Engineer* from Ravnica) and lineages (such as the *Mark of Handling* Human from Eberron) have spells that are "added to the spell list of your spellcasting class", and a couple of magic items might contain spells that "are wizard spells for you while you are attuned to it".

Given that for an Order of Scribes wizard:

> "When you cast a wizard spell with a spell slot, you can temporarily replace its damage type with a type that appears in another spell in your spellbook...The latter spell must be of the same level as the spell slot you expend."

How many spells can you add, in one character, from sources like these to the Wizard spell list that are useful for the Awakened Spellbook, as a source or target of a type of damage to be replaced?

Comment: Are you asking about the number of spells that are added to spell lists in the manner you describe, or are you asking about the maximum number of spells any one character could gain to their spell list like this? Is your question restricted to official material only (I guess yes, because otherwise the answer is: all of them).

Comment: Maybe change your question to not say "useful" this sounds very opinion-based. Just specify that you are interested in spells to replace damage types.

Comment: @Slaves_of_the_Coast I'm interested in which options my character should pick to get both the most new damage types and spells to use alternative damage types with.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### First let's see what wizards can get by default

Using some searches on D&D Beyond, we can see what damage type options are available for Order of Scribes wizards from just the wizard list.

It turns out, most damage types are available for most levels. Here are the ones that aren't, along with non-wizard spells and dunamancy spells (kept separate since they are setting specific) that would fill in the gaps if they could be added to the wizard spell list for our Order of Scribes wizard:

| Level | Damage Types Missing | Non-Wizard Options | Dunamancy Spells |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st | necrotic, psychic, radiant, slashing | *arms of hadar*, *hex*, *inflict wounds* for necrotic; *dissonant whispers* for psychic; *divine favor*, *guiding bolt*, *wrathful smite* for radiant; |  |
| 2nd | force, piercing, radiant | *spiritual weapon* for force; *cordon of arrows* for piercing; *branding smite*, *moonbeam* for radiant |  |
| 3rd | force, piercing, poison, psychic, slashing |  | *pulse wave* for force |
| 4th | force, poison, slashing |  | *gravity sinkhole* for force |
| 5th | acid, lightning, piercing, slashing, thunder | *insect plague* for piercing; *wrath of nature* for slashing; *destructive wave* for thunder |  |
| 6th | acid, piercing, poison, slashing, thunder | *wall of thorns* for piercing; *blade barrier* for slashing |  |
| 7th | piercing, psychic, slashing, thunder |  |  |
| 8th | bludgeoning, force, piercing, slashing, thunder | *earthquake*, *tsunami* for bludgeoning | *dark star*, *reality break* for force |
| 9th | necrotic, piercing, radiant, slashing, thunder | *storm of vengeance* for thunder | *time ravage* for necrotic |

### Now let's see which of these are available

Unfortunately, there aren't too many of the above non-wizard options to fill in the gaps from other features that add them to the wizard spell list. Here are the ones available:

- *dissonant whispers* from the Rakdos Cultist background
- *guiding bolt* from the Boros Legionnaire background
- *inflict wounds* from the Witherbloom Student background
- *insect plague* from the Golgari Agent background
- *destructive wave* from the Gruul Anarch background

Comment: this table is great. really useful for knowing what damage types to look out for. would the _hallow_ spell from Halfling (Mark of Hospitality) add in some missing damage types at 5th level?

Comment: and the Witherbloom Student background adds _inflict wounds_ for necrotic I think?

Comment: @yeastgoblin Interesting that the Ravnica backgrounds worked when searching D&D beyond for the spells and selecting the Compendium filter, but Witherbloom didn't. I edited to include these.

Comment: @yeastgoblin I'm not sure how *hallow* interacts with Order of Scribes. I'd probably ask this question separately.

Comment: What about upcasting?  Suppose I had access to insect plague from Golgari Agent.  If I want to do piercing damage with a 3rd or 4th level spell, can't I upcast it to 5th level and then make it piercing?

Comment: @KirtnoQA4mewhilemodsstrike Yes; that is how the feature works. When you upcast, the spell changes level to match the slot used.

Comment: _aura of purity_ adds poison damage at 4th level?

Comment: I hope you don't mind me using your answer's comments section as a holder for information as I run across it. wizards already have _intellect fortress_ for psychic damage at 3rd level? otherwise the _Crystalline Chronicle_ gives you that.

Comment: @yeastgoblin That's not really the best place to store that information. You can certainly leave your own answer on the question though. Something along the lines of "David's answer captures a number of options, but here are some others that I've found." This way, other users can more easily leverage the work you've done to find other options. You can also edit that answer as you find other options.